# Form not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a simple content management system. I have a div that appears when the user clicks a link to add a new slide to an existing slideshow, where jquery plants the form into the div via a string.

The problem I am having is that nothing happens when I click the "upload" button and it doesn't seek out the upload_slide.php page. Anyone know why this may be happening? Here is part in question:

```
function showprompt(prompttype) {
    var prompttext = "";
    $('.prompt_inner').text(prompttext);

    if (prompttype=="slideprompt") {
        prompttext = '<table style="margin-right: 50px;"><form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_slide.php" method="post">';
        prompttext += '<tr><td colspan="2"><b>CREATE NEW SLIDE</b><td></tr>';
        prompttext += '<tr><td>SLIDE:</td><td><input name="new_slide" type="file" /></td></tr>';
        prompttext += '<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>';
        prompttext += '</form></table>';
        $('.prompt_inner').append(prompttext);
    }
}
```

Comment: That markup is *not* valid. You can't put a `form` *directly* inside a `table`.

Comment: I would really recommend against that kind of coding. There are things like Handlebars and Mustache that allow you to create templates for your content. Everything gets messy quickly when coding like that.

Comment: You'll most probably find that because you've placed the form in the wrong place it's actually been moved to collapsed and outside the table (from the point of view of the browser). Which means it wont be wrapping any of the fields you've placed within it... and so wont submit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move the form outside table

```
function showprompt(prompttype) {
    var prompttext = "";
    $('.prompt_inner').text(prompttext);

    if (prompttype=="slideprompt") {
        prompttext = '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_slide.php" method="post"><table style="margin-right: 50px;">';
        prompttext += '<tr><td colspan="2"><b>CREATE NEW SLIDE</b><td></tr>';
        prompttext += '<tr><td>SLIDE:</td><td><input name="new_slide" type="file" /></td></tr>';
        prompttext += '<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>';
        prompttext += '</table></form>';
        $('.prompt_inner').append(prompttext);
    }
}​
```